# Both mkdir(0 from File and forceMkdir() from FileUtils fail to create a folder that its name contains unicode characters. Any idea?

Tags: java, matlab, file-io, unicode

I want to create a folder, which has a `unicode` character in its name, using `Java` within a `Matlab` code. I tried both `mkdir()` of `java.io.File` and `forceMKdir()` of `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`. However, the unicode character is replaced with two characters, which are its UTF-8 representation, when the folder is created. Any idea? A sample code is below.

```
feature('DefaultCharacterSet', 'UTF-8')
u0_filename = 'é'
curre_output_dir =  java.lang.String(root_meddir).concat(java.lang.String(relative_output_meddir).concat(u0_filename).concat(java.lang.String(prior.slash_symbol)))
test_dir1 = java.io.File(curre_output_dir)
```

With `mkdir()`:

```
test_dir1.mkdir()
```

with `mkdirs()`:

```
test_dir1.mkdirs()
```

with `forceMkdir()`:

```
javaMethod('forceMkdir', 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils', test_dir1)
```

But, all create a folder with the name 'Ã©', which is incorrect. The file system is Ubuntu.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To use the `Files.createDirectory()`, as suggested by fge, I followed this steps:

1. Set the variable MATLAB_JAVA to the path to Java 7 JRE:

   > ```
   > $ export MATLAB_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7/jre/
   > ```
2. Start Matlab, and check the Java version:

   > ```
   > >> version -java
   > Java 1.7.0_55-b13 with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
   > ```
3. However, the methods do not seem to properly work:

> ```
> >> java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory('test') 
> No method 'createDirectory' with matching signature found for class 'java.nio.file.Files'.
> ```

Comment: If your underlying JVM is Java 7, use `Files.createDirectory()` instead; also, try and see what `file.encoding` is set to in the JVM.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that you provide a sample code on how to use `Files.createDirectory()`?

Comment: I don't know Matlab, so I can only provide a sample Java code ;)

Answer (score 0):

So I am answering the edit from May 9.

The reason why the code does not work at that point is because the wrong signature is being provided as the error message says.  You are passing a String to the method when it requires a Path object.

Now, [this](http://codingjunkie.net/java-7-copy-move/) tutorial illustrates three different ways of creating a Path object.  I will summarize because we hate links.

1. `Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test");` seems to do what you wish.
2. `Path path = Paths.get("test");` which also would work in your case as it is a shortcut for the item #1.
3. `File f = new File("test");Path path = f.toPath();`

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for you to rewrite one of these ways in the Matlab's Java syntax?